# Confusion in ReentrantLock

Tags: java, multithreading

I am trying to understand the internal working of ReentrantLock in Java.

I have created an example like:-

```
package com.thread.trylock;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.Lock;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock;

public class ReentrantLockingDemo {

    final Lock lock = new ReentrantLock();

    public static void main(final String... args) {

        new  ReentrantLockingDemo().go();

    }

    private void go() {

        Runnable run1 = newRunable();
        Thread t1 = new Thread(run1, "Thread1");
        System.out.println(run1.hashCode());
        t1.start();

        Runnable run2 = newRunable();
        Thread t2 = new Thread(run2, "Thread2");
        System.out.println(run2.hashCode());
        t2.start();

    }

    private Runnable newRunable() {

        return new Runnable() {

            @Override

            public int hashCode() {

                return super.hashCode();

            }

            @Override

            public void run() {

                do {

                    try {

                        if (lock.tryLock(500, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)) {

                            try {

                                System.out.println("locked thread "

                                        + Thread.currentThread().getName());


                                Thread.sleep(1000);


                            } finally {

                                lock.unlock();

                                System.out.println("unlocked locked thread "

                                        + Thread.currentThread().getName());

                            }

                            break;

                        } else {

                            System.out.println("unable to lock thread "

                                    + Thread.currentThread().getName()

                                    + " will re try again");

                        }

                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {

                        e.printStackTrace();

                    }

                } while (true);

            }     

        };

    }

}



//Output something like this (which may be slightly different on your machine)

locked thread Thread2

unable to lock thread Thread1 will re try again

locked thread Thread1

unlocked locked thread Thread2

unlocked locked thread Thread1
```

Now my question is that there are 2 threads objects and 2 runnable objects and 2 threads. Each thread should be running the run method on its own stack frame for a different runnable object. If each thread is running its own run method on stack with different runnable object the output should be different.

I have seen examples where we create few threads and we pass on a shared object onto those threads and we do lock and unlock in the method for that shared object. Here the object is not shared. There are 2 runnable objects passed to 2 threads objects but runnable object are behaving as shared object.

Can you please explain as what might be causing this output? or can provide some clarification on the same

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

> Here the object is not shared

It is correct that both threads are running an own instance of Runnable, so both threads are not sharing a common Runnable.

**But** both Runnable instances are using a shared object of the enclosed class, and this is the lock object. So they synchronize each other with the help of this object. One thread is blocked as long as the other one has a hold on the lock by calling

```
lock.tryLock(500, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
```

Why both Runnable instances have access to the lock object which is defined as private variable of the class ReentrantLockingDemo is explained here [Anonyomous Classes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html#accessing).

So when you write

```
private Runnable newRunable() {

    return new Runnable() {...};
}
```

you create a new instance of an anonymous inner class inherited from Runnable which has access to all final (or in Java 8 also all effectively final) fields of the outer class.

So even if you don't explicitly pass in a shared object to the Runnable instances, they do use a shared object for synchronization, in this case the lock object.

Comment: `this` is always final.

Comment: This is correct, but is this somehow related to the answer?

Comment: It's an additional note/clarification on the answer "Runnable which has access to all final ... fields"  The Runnable captures `this` which is always final.  Note: if it was a lambda it would capture the `lock` not `this`.

Comment: @GoyalVicky In general it is possible to synchronize threads with any kind of object using `synchronized(object)`, but since Java 1.5 and the introduction of the Lock interface and its implementations (here the ReentrantLock), they are commonly used for locking, especially if you need additional features. Here for example you use the `tryLock` which does not wait forever. This is not possible with a normal synchronized block.

Comment: @Peter Ah thanks for that. You are right, I forgot to mention it.

Comment: @Tommy  The only question I have is in case of concurrency(When I am using java.util.concurrent.locks) is it always this lock object which is shared between threads in case of single object or more objects (as in the above example) for synchronization? Although using it on different objects will not serve any purpose as the instance variable will also become thread-safe since the objects are different. In which case lock gets shared among threads and in which case this gets shared? Can you provide any link for the above?

Answer (score 2):

> Here the object is not shared.

The Runnable and Threas are not shared.

There is two object which are shared `ReentrantLockingDemo.this` and `ReentrantLockingDemo.this.lock`  It is the sharing of the lock which makes this work.

> runnable object are behaving as shared object.

You are not printing out the details of the Runnable, so there is no way for you to determine this.  Try adding the following inside the `run()`

```
System.out.println(this);
```

It should print the class name with a different hashCode after it.

> is it always this lock object which is shared between threads in case of single object or more objects (as in the above example) for synchronization?

There is nothing special about lock object which means it must be shared.  The reason the object is shared is due to the way the data structure is laid out.  You have one instance of ReentrantLockingDemo and it has one field which is an instance of ReentrantLock.  There is nothing more complicated or special than that.

> Although using it on different objects will not serve any purpose as the instance variable will also become thread-safe since the objects are different.

The only `different` objects are the two `Runnable`

> . In which case lock gets shared among threads

When both thread uses the same object.  In this case there is only one of them so there is no doubt it much be shared.

> Can you provide any link for the above?

Sometimes we imagine that because a problem is hard to grasp it must be complicated.  In fact it is really, very simple.

You only create one lock, so it must be shared.

Comment: Yes there are different hash Code values coming for runnable objects. So does Reentrant Object take the lock on the Object inside which it is instantiated. i.e ReentrantLockingDemo has a Reentrant object so it takes lock on ReentrantLockingDemo object? Is it equivalent to synchronized(this)?

Comment: The only lock you have defined in on an instance of that class so it is the only one you could be refering to.  `synchronized(this)` is different as `this` is not changed.  It is similar to `synchronized(lock)` or `synchronized(ReeentrantLockingDemo.this)`

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation